How to view guides for previous versions of Jetpack Compose Navigation
I am trying to work on bringing my Android code up to standard with the guidance given here - Encapsulate your navigation code  However, I don't have the toRoute method mentioned.  I do some digging and I find it is added in an alpha version of its library: Navigation Version 2.8.0-alpha08.  I would like to stay away from using prerelease versions in my production code, so I'd like to work off similar guidance that is against a previous version - in this case, the latest stable version.  I'd like to think that exists somewhere, but so far I am not having any luck finding it.
I know it is possible to select which version of docs I'm seeing in the Android SDK proper; I know this is a Jetpack Compose library, and not the Android SDK; and I know I'm asking about guides rather than the formal API reference.  Maybe it doesn't make as much sense to ask for any previous version's documentation, but at least the latest stable (as of writing, 2.7.7)?  Is it possible I might find that somewhere, if only for this Navigation library?

The current version is 2.8.0-beta02, so not a lot of major changes are expected and it won't take that long to the stable release (although I obviously cannot give you an upper bound). Until you need to release soon and won't be able to accomodate beta versions, I woud just suggest that you use the current beta. It makes navigation a lot easier with its new type-safe navigation arguments.

@Leviathan I definitely like the improvements in type-safety, and re: stability I take your point as someone more experienced in the Android dev community.  For my personal projects I'd probably be fine doing this, but my work environment is a bit gun shy of using pre-release material (pun only slightly intended :) - so I'd still like to see if looking up docs for previous versions of Jetpack Compose is possible.
